# Java get specific value from list and add to other list

Tags: java, spring, list, hibernate, rest

i want to ask some question, how to get specific value from list and add to another list, lets say i have list (this is cust list from hibernate DAO) like:

```
[["marketplace","001-002-003"],["insurance","142-523-132"],["car purchase","982349824"]]
```

i just want to get a value of "marketplace","insurance", and "car purchase" from that list and add to new list called "bu"

here is my code

```
public @ResponseBody String findBU(@RequestBody AllCustomerHist customer){
        BigDecimal id= customer.getId();
        String message;
        List<String> bu= new ArrayList<>();
        int i;

        System.out.println("ID = "+id);
        List<AllCustomerHist> cust = allCustomerHistService.findBU(id);


        for (i=0; i<cust.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("iteration = "+i);

            // stumbled here //
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("id", id);
        json.put("BU", bu);

        message = json.toString();
        return message;

    }
```

this is my AllCustomerHistDaoImpl class

```
//release 1.3
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<AllCustomerHist> findBU(BigDecimal adpId) {
    // TODO cek kodingan
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(AllCustomerHist.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("srctable"), "srctable")
                    .add(Projections.property("customerId"), "customerId"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("adpId", adpId));

    return (List<AllCustomerHist>)criteria.list();
}
```

Notice that AllCustomerHist is an entity class to define the table in hibernate

thank you for your helps :D

Comment: What's the structure of `AllCustomerHist`? More importantly, why do assume we would know?

Comment: Why are you using ID as BigDecimal?

Comment: You have shown the cust list from Hibernate in a way it looks like a Map. Then you're using a list with AllCustomerHist type elements. It seems it's not compatible.

Comment: @PauloPedroso the result of cust is not a pair of key:value, its result set from 2 column, first is srctable column ("marketplace, insurance, car purchase" is come from here) and the second is from customerID column

Comment: @galih maybe you should post the AllCustomerHist code.

Comment: @PauloPedroso already updated :D , AllCustoemrHist is an entity class, should i post it too? because its too long (800 line of code)

Comment: @galih if AllCustoemrHist class is a pojo with more than 800 lines, I am pretty sure the DAO return won't be [["marketplace","001-002-003"],["insurance","142-523-132"],["car purchase","982349824"]] as described.

Comment: Basically what you want as query result is the lisi of `srctable` related to the ID passed. Am I right? If I'm right why don't you modify the query by taking out only the `stctable` column?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata i cant take out the column, because i needed it to make validation in the next steps

Comment: At this point I guess you must create the `List<String> bu` in the cycle where you are stumbled. See my answer

Comment: SOLVED, i just need to add setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AllCustomerHist.class)) in my dao class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to make some validation and you need to take off the whole `AllCustomerHist`object what I would do is the following code

```
List<AllCustomerHist> cust = allCustomerHistService.findBU(id);
List<String> bu = new ArrayList<String>(cust.size());

        for (i=0; i<cust.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("iteration = "+i);
            AllCustomerHist aCust = cust.get(i);
            bu.add(aCust.getSrctable());

        }
//here your bu list should be ready to be used.....
```

I hope it's what you needed

Comment: it cannot casted from object to allcustomerhist, your code is correct, but i need to transform my resultset using setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AllCustomerHis‌​t.class))

Comment: Ah so the `AllCustomerHist` was not the entity class.... I understood it was the entity class otherwise I would have told you to use the hibernate transformer. Anyway I'm glad it works

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDK1.8+, you can also do it like this:

```
List<AllCustomerHist> cust = allCustomerHistService.findBU(id);
List<String> bu = cust.stream()
    .map(AllCustomerHist::getSrctable)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```